# Kendo datepicker control is not getting binded to label

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

This is my code

[image: Kendo datepicker unable to associate control with label]

dynamic id is getting generated for input tag but in the for attribute of label tag it says [Object object]

[image]

any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I checked the template variable, I found `focusableId` property which contains the input id. This can be set inside `for` attribute solves your issue.

When you click on the label the datepicker will get focussed!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <div class="example-config">
            Selected value is: {{value | kendoDate:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
        </div>
        <div class="example-wrapper" style="min-height: 400px">
            <label [for]="rDatePicker.focusableId">Select a date:</label>
            <kendo-datepicker id="date" name="date" #rDatePicker
                [(value)]="value"
            ></kendo-datepicker>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public value: Date = new Date(2000, 2, 10);
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendodatepicker-sample1-wdckrb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo UI for Angular library has dedicated Label and FloatingLabel components designed to associate a label with a complex component in which the actual focusable element is nested in the component rendering:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/labels/label/association/